# SQL Server replication - set PollingInterval in sp_addmergepushsubscription_agent

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

I am trying to create replication subscriptions to and `SQL Server 2008 R2` via a script. There are 3 subscribers so this script creates the subscriptions by calling

```
sp_addmergesubscription
```

and then

```
sp_addmergepushsubscription_agent
```

with the required parameters for each subscriber. The only thing I have not accomplished so far is to tell the sp_addmergepushsubscription_agent that I wish to set the `PollingInterval` to 30 seconds instead of the default 60 seconds. What parameters need to be changed in order to do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the PollingInterval Merge Agent parameter in the replication agent profile after you create your subscription and your subscription agent.

Have a look at [Work with Replication Agent Profiles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152515.aspx).

Comment: I know how to do this from the UI of the Management Studio. I'd just like to do it from within the scripts so i can avoid after running them to have to go to the replication agent of each subscriber and change this value.

Comment: See the section Using Transact-SQL in the link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152515.aspx  You need to look at sp_help_agent_profile and sp_change_agent_profile.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187318.aspx

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189840.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the links.

So, in a blank query window, i enter this: "sp_change_agent_profile 6, '-PollingInterval', 30"

and i get this: "Msg 21183, Invalid property name '-PollingInterval'"

Any idea why would this be happening?